# SAP DI: Ml Scenario Manager - Git

Tags: machine-learning

How do you manage the code (and notebooks) in the ML Scenario Manager workspace in SAP Data Intelligence?

It seems that SAP DI does not support a direct integration of Git.

Answer (score 0):

For every ML Scenario, there is a notebook section where you can upload/create files with code and/or Jupyter notebooks:
[image]